# SSRS IIF with multiple sums

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I would like to change the colour of a field if:
sum of EMGLIGHTING_Y_valid_count 
plus sum of EMGLIGHTING_Y_expired_count 
plus sum of EMGLIGHTING_NotPresentCount 
does not equal to block_count.

At the moment I have the below. I have tried switching round the Red and White colours, but this always come's back as White, even when I enter Red and Pruple. This makes me think there is something wrong with the below.

```
=IIF((Sum(Fields!EMGLIGHTING_Y_valid_count.Value) + 
Sum(Fields!EMGLIGHTING_Y_expired_count.Value) + 
Sum(Fields!EMGLIGHTING_NotPresentCount.Value)) <> 
Sum(fields!block_count),"Red","White")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the field value, otherwise you are comparing an integer to an object.

```
Sum(fields!block_count.Value),"Red","White")
```